# merge data for two columns having same values

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV files where column1 (ensembl_gene_id) in df1 and and column1 (gene1) in df2 have same values in few rows. I want to merge my data for df1 (column1) and df2(column2) having same values.
I tried a script given below (I realize the code has too many errors):

```
import os
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame()
for item in os.listdir('./'):
    if item.endswith('.csv'):
        df1 = pd.read_csv('gene1-protein.csv')
        df2 = pd.read_csv('gene1.csv')
        df = pd.Dataframe.merge(df1, df2, on=['ensembl_gene_id', 'gene1']
print(df)
```

My files look like-

```
 df1
ensembl_gene_id hgnc_symbol gene_biotype
ENSG00000000419 DPM1        protein_coding
ENSG00000000938 FGR         protein_coding
ENSG00000000938 FGR         protein_coding
ENSG00000001084 GCLC        protein_coding

df2
gene1
ENSG00000000419.11
ENSG00000000938.11
ENSG00000001084.9
ENSG00000001084.9
```

How can I merge my data in a separate csv file for df1 (column1) and df2(column2) having same values?

My expected result should look like-

```
gene1              ensembl_gene_id  hgnc_symbol gene_biotype
ENSG00000000419.11 ENSG00000000419  DPM1        protein_coding
ENSG00000000938.11 ENSG00000000938  FGR         protein_coding
ENSG00000000938.11 ENSG00000000938  FGR         protein_coding
ENSG00000001084.9  ENSG00000001084  GCLC        protein_coding
```

Comment: Can you show the result you would like to get?

Comment: do you mean  `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`  ?

Comment: @raphael yes I want to concatenate the data based on equal values in first columns in both the data frames. But, some of the values are in repetition in df2 and I don't want to omit the repetitions as well. basically the dataset in df1 is around 100k while in df2 it is 350k approximately (due to repetitions).

Comment: if you have duplicates in your index you need to decide on what to do with them first... (or even better assess where they are coming from?)  there's no way pandas can decide it for you...     why do you need 2 rows with identical entries?

Comment: @raphael I am doing a graphical analysis on this data in which there are certain concepts that require these duplications. Unfortunately, these duplications are more relevant to me so I can't skip them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, if you really need to keep your duplicates, that's how you could do it.
(assuming the value after the dot in df2 is always the same for a given ensembl_gene_id)

```py
# ----- just to reproduce the dataframes
import pandas as pd
df1_s = "ensembl_gene_id hgnc_symbol gene_biotype\n\
ENSG00000000419 DPM1        protein_coding\n\
ENSG00000000938 FGR         protein_coding\n\
ENSG00000000938 FGR         protein_coding\n\
ENSG00000001084 GCLC        protein_coding"

df2_s = "gene1\n\
ENSG00000000419.11\n\
ENSG00000000938.11\n\
ENSG00000001084.9\n\
ENSG00000001084.9"

df1 = pd.DataFrame([i.split() for i in df1_s.split("\n")])
df1.columns = df1.iloc[0]
df1.drop(0, inplace=True)
df1.set_index("ensembl_gene_id", inplace=True)

df2 = pd.DataFrame([i.split() for i in df2_s.split("\n")])
df2.columns = df2.iloc[0]
df2.drop(0, inplace=True)

# -------------------------------------------------


# make the index of df2 similar to df1
df2.set_index(df2.gene1.str.split(".").str[0], inplace=True)

# append the values 
# (you need to drop duplicates since "same-index-values" are propagated automatically)
df1["gene1"] = df2["gene1"].drop_duplicates()
```

```py
print(df1)
>>>                 hgnc_symbol    gene_biotype               gene1
>>> ensembl_gene_id                                                
>>> ENSG00000000419        DPM1  protein_coding  ENSG00000000419.11
>>> ENSG00000000938         FGR  protein_coding  ENSG00000000938.11
>>> ENSG00000000938         FGR  protein_coding  ENSG00000000938.11
>>> ENSG00000001084        GCLC  protein_coding   ENSG00000001084.9
```

Comment: although I needed duplicates, but still this made my task much easier. Thanks a lot.